# The best way to add loads of sounds on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, css

I am creating a browsergame in ASP.NET (using AJAX, jQuery, ect. - NO Flash). In this game I need to play some sound files. Right now I have those files as .WAV, but if the solution can play .MP3, that is preferred.

I have several events during the game which need sounds: You hit the monster, you die, you level up, ect. The page is based upon update panels, which means I will have to add several sounds (and replay them at specific events) without a postback. As some of the sounds is replayed every 3-5th second and others are played way more rare, it has to be efficient to this requirement.

What would be the best and most efficient solution to solve this? :-)

Thanks a lot!
Best regards,
Lars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 ready browsers have the ability to play sounds and videos without any flash. I am not sure about using javascript or AJAX.

For reference to HTML5 sounds (`<audio>`) http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

There is a very interesting tutorial on different ways of playing sounds in a browser over here http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm which could help you a lot.

Comment: Yep - I read some about it, and it seems really awesome - when it is available. The only problem is I don't really feel happy with releasing a product only very few browsers support.. :) THE solution when HTML 5 is fully supported though.

Comment: HTML5 is already available for for use in most modern browsers (i.e. Firefox, Chrome etc.) HTML5 will be available in the newest version of InternetExplorer. I am unaware of the current position of HTML5 on other browsers. But it will take as long as it takes, there is no set 'release' date, it's already there if the browser knows how to interoperate it.